# Whats the difference between main and secondary methods in scala and how to execute mulitple functions in the scala class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am beginner in scala coming from python. I am testing execution results from a Scala class in `intellij`. But I am confuse what to call these `methods` and how it is being executed in some cases. Please help me to understand `4` parts...

**1** - Is calling `secondary methods` correct ???

```
object scala {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a : List[Int] =  List(1,2)
    val b = a.filter(x => x!=2)
    println("main result...")
    println(b)
  }
  def count_(args: Array[String]): Unit = { //2.  why it is not executable, what i am missing??? 
    val a = List("best", "a", "a", "b")
    val a_adv = a.map(x => (x,1))
    println("not main result")
    println(a_adv)
  }
  def count_ex(lst: List[String]): List[(String,Int)] = { //3. why its differnt from count_ ???
    val a_adv = lst.map(x => (x, 1))
    a_adv
  }
  println("not main external")
  println(count_ex(List("best", "a", "a", "b")))
}
```

**output**

```
not main external // missing count_ execution why???
List((best,1), (a,1), (a,1), (b,1))
main result...
List(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The body of your `object`, the code outside of any `def`s, constitutes the "static initializer" for the object.  This code is executed at the time the class is loaded by the JVM (I'm assuming JVM here, but the semantics should also be the same for the other Scala targets, e.g. JS or Native).

The code inside the `def`s is not executed unless and until the method defined by the `def` is called.

If this class is handed to the JVM as the entrypoint (e.g. with `java scala$` or similar), then after loading the class, the JVM will call the `main` method.

For example, if you modified `main` to include:

```scala
count_(args)
```

Then the `count_` method would be called.

Since `count_ex` was called as part of the static initializer, it gets called at the time of class loading.

Note that you could move

```scala
println(count_ex(List("best", "a", "a", "b")))
```

before the `def count_ex` and it would still work.

Comment: Thanks, last thing why count_ not being called like main ? ( i am using ide intellij)  and i modify *main name to *main_ in Object, i am not able to execute the code itself.

Comment: `main` is a special method name in the JVM.  A program running on the JVM needs a `main` method somewhere (not every class needs to have a `main`, but there needs to be at least one class with a `main` method in order to execute anything).